# Deep mixin code "works" but I cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, node.js, mixins

I wrote this code, but I cannot figure out why it works.

```
const mixin = (a, b) => {

  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(b)) {

    if (!(val && typeof val === 'object')) {
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    if(!(a[key] && typeof a[key] === 'object')){
      a[key] = b[key];
      continue;
    }

    if (a[key] === b[key]) {
      continue;
    }


    mixin(a[key], b[key]);

  }

  return a;

};


const deepMixin = (...v) => {
  return v.reduce((a, b) => mixin(a, b), {});
};



const m1 = {
  bar: '1',
  foo() {
    return 'm1';
  }
};

const m2 = {
  bar: '2',
  foo() {
    return 'm2';
  }
};

m2.foo.bar = 2;


const m3 = {
  bar: '3',
  foo() {
    return 'm3';
  }
};

m3.foo.bar = 3;


console.log(deepMixin(m1, m2, m3).foo());  // m3
console.log(deepMixin(m1, m2, m3).foo.bar);  // 3

// works, but why
```

basically, `deepMixin` behaves just like `Object.assign`. There are two differences:

1. deepMixin always returns a new object (immutable).
2. it traverses sub-properties instead of only operating on top-level props.

but I cannot figure out why calling

```
console.log(deepMixin(m1, m2, m3).foo());  // m3
```

there is nothing in my code that I can see that copies the top level foo property from the rhs (b) to the lhs (a) object.

Anybody know why the code "works"?

Comment: doing `m3.foo.bar = 3;` etc is going to set it, its not going to overwrite the method [*](https://playcode.io/373885?tabs=script.js,preview,console). you're getting m3 because of the order, you are specifically overriding the last method, which is why foo = m3

Comment: I don't follow. Where am I overriding the last method?

Comment: reduce is a loop, it iterates over the spreaded values of `v`, then the last item/object is then set somewhere in your `a[key] = b[key]` bits. Change the order and then it should be clear `deepMixin(m1, m3, m2)`.